# How to correctly get length of array

Tags: javascript, arrays, vue.js

I'm having a bit of a problem so i have an array with objects when i log it it displays everything fine but when i try the `.length` function it returns `0` for some reason.

Here's my code:

```
async getTicketType(updatedTicketType) {
    await this.getTicketTypes();
    if (this.typeOptions) {
        console.log('ik kom hier');
        console.log(this.typeOptions);
        console.log(this.typeOptions.length);
        for (let i = 0; i < this.typeOptions.length; i++) {
            console.log('ik kom hier');
            if (this.typeOptions[i]["value"] === updatedTicketType) {
                this.currentTypeOptions = this.typeOptions[i];
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And here's a picture of the logs:

[image: And here's a picture of the logs]

Comment: Try `this.typeOptions.value.length`

Comment: Try reading [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52873516/9787887)

Answer (score 0):

This is because your array has 10 undefined values therefore it does not actually have a length property, if you make sure that there is some value in each element then you will be able to get the array.
It's a feature of JS and how the length property on the array is computed.

Comment: The values are filled. the this.getTicketTypes fills this.typeOptions through an api call

Comment: What does the data look like? are you sure that it actually came?

Comment: Yeah every iteration has a label and a value which are filled label is filled with a String and Value with an integer

Comment: please share you api code so we can get a better sense of the data you are referring to

Answer (score 0):

You can try to parse it to an array again:

```
// arr is an array with contains 10 items
var arr = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.typeOptions));
```

Then, continuing with the loop...