# how can i remove __ob__: Observer from my array list?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

i have an array

```
data = [38589, 3, __ob__: Observer];
```

i want to send a put request API with the body sending this array. and got a 400 error?
is it this `__ob__: Observer` thing is being a problem for me to sending this data? if it's the one that affect the error, can i know how to remove it from my array?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Vue JS returns \[\_\_ob\_\_: Observer\] data instead of my array of objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52873516/vue-js-returns-ob-observer-data-instead-of-my-array-of-objects)

Comment: It probably isn't the `__ob__` that is causing your problem. You can inspect the details of the request using the Network tab of your browser's developer tools. That should allow you to see exactly what is being sent and from there you can figure out what the problem is.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can convert it to JSON and then back, if you want to get the final value of the array without the observer:

```
const finalData = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data));
```

Comment: I don't know if anyone tried to measure which method was more efficient, so I used a simple comparison model. If someone confirms it in a more appropriate way, it would be welcome. My test criterion was to compare between 3 ways I know how to convert: `Object.assign`, `JSON.stringify into JSON.parse`, `const unwrapped = { ...this.vars }`. It looping 100000 iterations, in my computer `const unwrapped = { ...this.vars }` it was much faster than the others, a total of `1462.4199999962002 ms`. The others, `5084.745000000112 ms` and `8934.004999988247 ms` respectively.

Comment: What about nested objects and arrays? Does it work?

Answer (score 8):

I know this is already 3 months old but you also can use this

```
const final_data = Array.from(data);
```

Comment: This did not work for me, nor did the spread operator or object.assign(). The accepted answer was the only one I could get to work.

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this:

```
const finalData = { ...data }
```