# Why JavaScript push method is storing data as Vue JS observer instead of normal array

Tags: javascript, vue.js

After I call the API I got this result:

```
[
    {
        "id_auto_mapping": 1,
        "feed_field": "id",
        "internal_field": "id"
    },
    {
        "id_auto_mapping": 2,
        "feed_field": "url",
        "internal_field": "url"
    },
    {
        "id_auto_mapping": 3,
        "feed_field": "price",
        "internal_field": "price"
    }
]
```

and I loop through the result and save the keys to `autoMappings` array:

```
if( response.data.success ) {
    if( response.data.auto_mappings.length > 0 ) {
        response.data.auto_mappings.forEach( ( item ) => {
            this.autoMappings.push(item.feed_field)
        })
    }
}
```

Now, If I do console like:

```
console.log( this.autoMappings )
```

I got this result:

[image]

1. Why is it saving as an observer instead of normal array?
2. How can I loop through the observer?

Comment: Please ask **one** question per question, not two or more.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder OOPS! I didn't know about it that I can not ask more than 1 questions.

Comment: This question might be related [remove observer from array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59610658/how-can-i-remove-ob-observer-from-my-array-list) tl;dr Parse to JSON and back. `const array = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.autoMappings))`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how can i remove \_\_ob\_\_: Observer from my array list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59610658/how-can-i-remove-ob-observer-from-my-array-list)

Comment: @D.Schaller I used that `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.autoMappings))` it's showing me empty array like `[]`

Comment: this is what I can see without and with `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.autoMappings))`: https://prnt.sc/TFLyPHxRLUJm

Comment: Means that it's changed asynchronously and it's really empty at the time when you access it.

Answer (score 0):

you can convert the observer into an array like this  :

```
var parsedobj = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(obj))
console.log(parsedobj)
```

Comment: This is what I can see: https://prnt.sc/aiPiDREjHeu0

Comment: It's showing me empty array