# VueJS - logging localStorage item returns correct result, but assign same item to var returns {__ob__: Observer}

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm trying to understand why this is happening.

In `created()` of my Vue component, if I console.log a localStorage item directly I get the correct result.

```
console.log(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("currentRoom"))); // correct object
```

But if I assign the localStorage item to a local variable and console that I get sadness. Why?

```
this.currentRoom = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("currentRoom"));
console.log(this.currentRoom); // {__ob__: Observer}
```

Comment: It means it's reactive. If you use it anywhere in your components and change it afterwards, your components will react to the change. It's not a bug, it's a feature.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Vue JS returns \[\_\_ob\_\_: Observer\] data instead of my array of objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52873516/vue-js-returns-ob-observer-data-instead-of-my-array-of-objects). Also see Evan You's (Vue's author) comment here: https://github.com/vuejs/Discussion/issues/292