# How to get value [__ob__: Observer] in vuejs

Tags: vue.js, vue-component

I'm working on the code at `Info.vue`

```
data() {
        return {
       option: [],
    }
}

created() {
  console.log(this.option);
}

methods: {
// I get the value from the form on change
  myChange: function (name, age) {
   this.option.push({name: name, age: age})
}
```

result :

```
[__ob__: Observer]
0:
name: ("zoka")
age: ("18")
__ob__: Observer {value: {…}, dep: Dep, vmCount: 0}
```

I can't get the value in **this.option**, give me an idea. Thanks

Comment: `option` will be wrapped in an observable object in order for the Vue mechanics to work. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52873516/vue-js-returns-ob-observer-data-instead-of-my-array-of-objects). Are you having a problem using the value in your code, or are you just confused by the `console.log` output?

Comment: hmm..I got the value when i change the input, and i want to put that value in an array :option..But the return result i cant get the result in option

Comment: related question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52873516/vue-js-returns-ob-observer-data-instead-of-my-array-of-objects

Answer (score 1):

@json see below for how best to see what you have within your data property `option`. Where exactly are you trying to see your `option` property? In the console logs or in your template?

```
<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      option: [],
    };
  },
  watch: {
    option() {
      // or check in a watcher. This will fire
      // anytime the `option` property is updated
      console.log("option within watcher:", this.option);
    },
  },
  methods: {
    myChange(name, age) {
      this.option.push({ name, age });

      // you can check here if you want
      console.log("option within myChange:", this.option);
    },
  },
  created() {
    // option is the default of an empty array here
    console.log("option within created:", this.option);
  },
};
</script>
```

You really should invest time into reading the Vue docs though. They've spent a lot of time putting them together and they can easily answer this question for you.
The official docs can be found [here](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/).
Read the docs and become familiar with Vue and it will become a lot more enjoyable. You'll be flying through it all in no time :)

Comment: Thank you for your advice, but i still can't get the data from `[__ob__: Observer]`.

Comment: @json do you mean when you log the output of option in created() it doesn't have the data? Try just rendering the output of option in your template like {{ option }} and see if there are values there. Or check in mounted()