# How i cann loop over my array when its an observer object

Tags: arrays, vue.js, vuejs2, axios

i want to iterate over an array, however my array is an observer. i have tried several ways, like converting to an array. nothing works.
does anyone have a suggested solution?
i'm pretty stuck on this.
here is my code:

```
var vm = new Vue({
el: '#app',
data() {
    return {
        segmenteConfig: []
    }
},
methods: {
    async loadData(type) {
        var url = null;
        console.log("used configs  -> ", this.segmenteConfig);
        this.segmenteConfig.forEach(segmenteConfig => {

            if (segmenteConfig.type === type) {
                url = segmenteConfig.url;
                console.log("used configs url -> ", url);
            }
        })
    }
    loadConfig() {
        var config = [];
        axios.get("ressources/segmente.json")
            .then(response => {
                response.data.Segmente.forEach(segmentConfig => {
                    this.segmenteConfig.push(segmentConfig);
                });
            });

    }

},
created() {
    this.loadConfig();
    this.loadData('internet');
}
```

});

[image: Console]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Vue JS returns \[\_\_ob\_\_: Observer\] data instead of my array of objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52873516/vue-js-returns-ob-observer-data-instead-of-my-array-of-objects)

Comment: Just use `segmenteConfig` normally (e.g: `<div v-for="segment in segmenteConfig"></div>`). `__ob__` simply means it's a reactive property (whenever it changes, Vue re-renders as necessary). If you want to see its value in console. use `.value` on any `__ob__`.