# How to ensure only one value gets pushed Javascript array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, vuejs2

Using Vue.js 2. I have a list of objects I'm displaying to the user. An entity of that object specifically. Here's a screen of the object (only showing 1 for brevity) and the list it's displayed in

[image]

```
<v-sheet elevation="10" rounded class="py-4 px-1">
      <div class="text-center text-caption">
        Device Serial Number {{ this.deviceOptions.length }}
           </div>
             <v-chip-group
                multiple
                active-class="primary--text"
                v-model="deviceOptions"
              >
             <v-chip
                v-for="item in $store.state.responeArray"
                  :key="item.key"
                  @click="countDevices(item)" // pass this selected object to a method
             >
                  {{ item.DeviceSerialNumber }}
                </v-chip>
            </v-chip-group>
 </v-sheet>
```

[image]

When one of these items are clicked I pass the item object to a method where I add the CollectionId to an array if it doesn't exist.

The object gets passed correctly, and I check if it exists in the array. If it doesn't, I add it. If I deselect, I check and remove it. here's that method.

```
countDevices(e) {
      if (this.deviceOptions.indexOf(e.CollectionId) >= 0) {
        for(let i = 0; i < this.deviceOptions.length; i++) {
          if (this.deviceOptions[i] === e.CollectionId){
            this.deviceOptions.splice(i, 1);
            
          }
        }

        console.log(this.deviceOptions.length);
        console.log(this.deviceOptions);
      } else {
        this.deviceOptions.unshift(e.CollectionId);
        console.log(this.deviceOptions.length);
        console.log(this.deviceOptions);
      }
    },
```

The actual problem

However, when you add to the array, it adds two values. not just one. I can't tell what that extra value is, but I think it's the *observer* vue uses.

Take notice of the length displayed that console where the value is present and *observer*

[image]

There's only one item selected, but length is showing 2. Whereas my goal is to show the counted number of indexes within the array.

Can anyone assist in this?

[image]

Comment: Is there anywhere else that you add elements to or otherwise populate `this.deviceOptions` ?

Comment: @ James. Great question, but there is not. I only use it there to add/remove those values.

Comment: So if you had console.log(this.deviceOptions) at the top of countDevices, it shows an empty array on the first click?

Comment: Yes. I'll edit and add a screenshot so you can see.. I log out the this.deviceOptions at the top of the method and this is what is shown.

Comment: Hm, but the "empty" array already has the observer in it.  [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52873516/vue-js-returns-ob-observer-data-instead-of-my-array-of-objects) mentions a similar phenomenon, but as the result of an unfinished async process (so "__ob__" is a placeholder for data that has not finished loading yet)

Comment: That's odd. This object is already returned from the API and sitting in a vuex store array. Hence the list I'm displaying in. deviceOption is an array I create locally on the component and solely use to count how many of those icons are clicked. I guess I'm saying is by this point I'm no longer waiting for an async method to finish.