# Vuex store getter returns [__ob__: Observer] on page refresh

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vuex, getter

Given the following code my Veux store getter returns `[__ob__: Observer]` whenever I refresh the page. I am using Vue 2.2.3 and TypeScript.

The data loads correctly on first load, which is coming from an external API, but when using the getter it fails and the API must be called again to retrieve the page data.

Here is the console log after initial page load.

`[{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, __ob__: Observer]`

There are 4 objects, which is correct, and the data is displayed on the page. However I don't know why there is an `Observer` added to the end.

Given that the getter works on first load, I know that the setter which adds the data to the store after retrieving from the API also is working correctly.

The same console log produces only the `Observer` when I refresh the page.

`[__ob__: Observer]`

This is what the getter in my store looks like.

```js
get getItems() {
  console.log('Store items -> ', this.items) // return empty array on page refresh
  // Suggested solution from another SO question 
  var parsedObj = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.items)) 
  return parsedObj
}
```

As shown above, I have tried the solution proposed in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52873516/vue-js-returns-ob-observer-data-instead-of-my-array-of-objects), but it still doesn't work.

The component using the store has a pretty basic getter call. Again this works fine on first page load but not after refresh.

```js
async created() {
  const result = await myModule.getItems
  console.log('[dev page] items from store -> ', result) // empty on refresh
  this.fmData = result 
  console.log('fm in Created -> ', this.fmData) // Observer only on refresh
}
```

I know Pinia would probably be a better store solution today, but unfortunately I am stuck with Vuex on this project for the moment.

I am unsure how to remedy this issue from here.

Comment: There is maybe something added to the array that is quite unexpected. I recommend that you start checking with the help of your Vue devtools.

Comment: The Observer is not something of concern when working with the reactive vuex state. Have you confirmed that the data is fetched from API on page refresh? It seems the store is not populated yet when the getter is invoked.

Comment: @IgorMoraru the data is not being fetched from the external API on page refresh because I want it to come from the store instead. My code checks the store first every time the page is loaded. In one of the components If there is nothing in the store then it will fetch from the API. I thought that was one of the points of using the Vuex but maybe I am mistaken. If so then I guess I'll just have to fetch the data every time the page is refreshed or use something else to persist the data. Thanks!

Comment: Here you go for the persistency: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66872372/8816585

Comment: @kissu Yes, local storage was the first thing that came to mind. It could end up being too much for local storage to handle though so I'll have to explore the options. But it's good to know that Vuex/Pinia do not persist data. That's an eye-opener. Thanks for the link!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use any store (Vuex or Pinia), there will be no persistency by default. Those things are not to be handled by Vue anyway. Hopefully, there is plenty of extensions for both store that will allow that.

Here is my [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66872372/8816585) with all the relevant links.

Answer (score 0):

At least in my case, after spending few hours, I figured out that you must set the value in the store using `actions` that calls the `mutations`.
Example:

```
mutations: {
    setUserId(state, id) {      
        state.activeUserId = id;
    }
},
actions: {
    updateUserId: ({commit, state}, id) => {
        commit('setUserId', id)
        return state.activeUserId;
    }
}
```

When I was using just the mutation, I got observer, when I added the action, the issue was resolved and I could access the `this.$store.state.activeUserId` from any view.